# Water heater flue and fresh air intake letting in pests

Tags: insulation, furnace, ducts, mice

The heater is in a closet in hallway. The flue is going up into attic. Attic insulation 3 yrs ago filled duct (pink insulation). Placed bug traps in closet, nothing 1st year. Lived in place 7 years total. But now bug traps are filled with all kinds of bugs and they are coming into hallway, etc. Also the pink attic insulation is scattered about and though the pipe opening is at almost floor level, the insulation is even on top of furnace. Could be mice coming in too. Can I seal the flue?

I can't do anything in attic at this time (long story). I have to fix it at furnace level inside.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about some pictures of the problem.

Comment: [Edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/250213/edit) your question and used the button with 'mountains' to add some pics, or upload them to somewhere like [imgur](imgur.com] and post a link to them so that someone else can add them.

Comment: What is a "water furnace"? Doesn't any furnace heat things? Please revise to clarify.

Comment: White stuff is just bug powder. 2 pipes, 1 from top of furnace and 1 from back wall of closet. See pictures added. Thank you brhans for directions on how to add pictures

Comment: 2 pipes, 1 from top of furnace, 1 along back wall with the insulation coming out at bottom

Comment: The first and third of your pictures are of the gas water heater's exhaust flue and must not be filled with insulation. If it is, it will fill your house with carbon monoxide and kill you.

Answer (score 2):

That is the flue for the water heater. Water is causing corrosion from the exterior. It is very unlikely that pests are entering through it; possibly at a poor fit between duct and protection ring ( difficult to see in the photo). The source of water should be corrected. It should probably be a type B duct ( double wall).

Comment: The flue is the picture of top pipe. The other picture shows the pipe Next to the water furnace,  near the back of it.  Sorry the pictures came out a bit dark. At bottom of silver pipe behind the water heater is the pink insulation coming out of it at bottom. Thank you for information on the flue pipe will look into it too.

Comment: I just added another picture to show better the pipe with the pink insulation coming out of it

Comment: Both flue and silver pipe look to be vented into attic. There is pink attic insulation on top of furnace as well. The posted pictures unfortunately are darker than what my cellphone shows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get a professional as you state the flue is well vented into the attic, that should go outside. The hot water heater exhaust contains Water, CO (Carbon Monoxide) and CO2 (Carbon dioxide). Both gases CO and CO2 are a deadly and silent poison that will kill you. They are heavier then air and will migrate down probably through any leak in the ceiling. The water has probably already destroyed your insulation.

Comment: One of my concerns is because in my old house before this, rats chewed their way into the attic,  destroyed the insulation and then chewed their way into the heater furnace that was in the hallway during winter. So if these vents are opened, rats or mice don't even have to chew to get in this time to get into the hallway closet with water heater and this seems to have started likely in winter. That the pink insulation is scattered throughout the closet area shouldn't happen by itself.

Comment: Since there is the flue pipe, is the other pipe unnecessarily and can be capped? Hallway closet has no outside walls, this is an old 1950s place.

Comment: The second pipe is likely to let in air for combustion. If so, it should not be filled with fiberglas insulation. Depending on how well sealed the house is, the second duct  may not be necessary.

Comment: Thank you blacksmith37 and Gil